# Problema con CORS al correr api rest web en ios y android

Tags: android, ios, fetch, asp.net-web-api

tengo una aplicación web creada en react.
La aplicación hace una llamada a una api de esta forma:

```
   let requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:": "*" },
    body: f,
    mode: 'cors'
  };
  try {
    return fetch(`${apipath}api/producto`, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        return result;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Al hacer el llamado a la api todo funciona en ordenadores, pero en el móvil ya sea safari o google chrome, ios o android me aparece este error:

> Fetch API cannot load **(url)** due to access control checks.

contenido del header.

Request Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: privado
Origin: privado
Referer: privado
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Lo raro es que si hago la solicitud desde el movil mediante el link de la api me anda, pero con fetch no.

Comment: Te da lo mismo si cambias `"*"` por `origin`?

Comment: Sigue igual a como antes

Comment: Lo raro es que si hago la solicitud desde el movil mediante el link de la api me anda, pero con fetch no.

Answer (score 0):

Este detalle lo he tenido precisamente en Safari, agrega en la url el último slash ( `${apipath}api/producto` ):

```
 return fetch(`${apipath}api/producto/`, requestOptions)
```

al parecer esta falla se debe a la comprobación de los recursos en caché.